# Pandas, multiply part of one DF against another based on condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Pretty new to this and am having trouble finding the right way to do this.

Say I have dataframe1 looking like this with column names and a bunch of numbers as data:

```
 D  L  W  S

 1  2  3  4

 4  3  2  1

 1  2  3  4
```

and I have dataframe2 looking like this:

```
Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4

2     data    data    D

3     data    data    S

4     data    data    L

5     data    data    S

6     data    data    W
```

I would like a new dataframe produced with the result of multiplying each row of the second dataframe against each row of the first dataframe, where it multiplies the value of Name1 against the value in the column of dataframe1 which matches the Name4 value of dataframe2.

Is there any nice way to do this? I was trying to look at using methods like `where`, `condition`, and `apply` but haven't been understanding things well enough to get something working.

EDIT: Use the following code to create fake data for the DataFrames:

```
d1 = {'D':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'W':[2,2,2,2,2,2],'L':[6,5,4,3,2,1],'S':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}

d2 = {'col1': [3,2,7,4,5,6], 'col2':[2,2,2,2,3,4], 'col3':['data', 'data', 'data','data', 'data', 'data' ], 'col4':['D','L','D','W','S','S']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)
```

EDIT AGAIN FOR MORE INFO

First I changed the data in df1 at this point so this new example will turn out better.
Okay so from those two dataframes the data frame I'd like to create would come out like this if the multiplication when through for the first four rows of df2. You can see that Col2 and Col3 are unchanged, but depending on the letter of Col4, Col1 was multiplied with the corresponding factor from df1:

d3 = { 'col1':[3,6,9,12,15,18,12,10,8,6,4,2,7,14,21,28,35,42,8,8,8,8,8,8], 'col2':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'col3':['data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data','data'], 'col4':['D','D','D','D','D','D','L','L','L','L','L','L','D','D','D','D','D','D','W','W','W','W','W','W']}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = d3)

Comment: Please provide a version of your dataframes that can be copied into a python console.

Comment: Yes sir, I've added an edit with info that can make dataframes like what I described.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things a lot easier! But I'm not sure I understand your description. Could you also add the dataframe you wish to create?

Comment: Hi peer, I've added an example for the goal dataframe. I want to say I really appreciate you taking a look at my question because I am really stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. You want to multiply each row `r` in `df2` with the corresponding column `c` in `df1` but the elements from `c` are only multiplied with the first element in `r` the rest of the row doesn't change.

I was thinking there might be a way to join `df1.transpose()` and `df2` but I didn't find one.
While not pretty, I think the code below solves your problem:

```
def stretch(row): 
    repeated_rows = pd.concat([row]*len(df1), axis=1, ignore_index=True).transpose() 
    factor = row['col1'] 
    label  = row['col4'] 
    first_column = df1[label] * factor 
    repeated_rows['col1'] = first_column 
    return repeated_rows                                                                                                                                  


pd.concat((stretch(r) for _, r in df2.iterrows()), ignore_index=True)                                                                                                        
#resulting in

   col1 col2  col3 col4
0     3    2  data    D
1     6    2  data    D
2     9    2  data    D
3    12    2  data    D
4    15    2  data    D
5    18    2  data    D
0    12    2  data    L
1    10    2  data    L
2     8    2  data    L
3     6    2  data    L
4     4    2  data    L
5     2    2  data    L
0     7    2  data    D
1    14    2  data    D
2    21    2  data    D
3    28    2  data    D
4    35    2  data    D
5    42    2  data    D
0     8    2  data    W
1     8    2  data    W
2     8    2  data    W
3     8    2  data    W
4     8    2  data    W
5     8    2  data    W
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much peer! This helps a lot. I know I could have done this with Lists, but I'm wanting to learn Pandas now and couldn't think of how to do it. This gives me a good idea now on how to do such things with Pandas.